# Why is there space between my 2 divs even though I made them overlap?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend

The top of the text should be in line with the top of the image, but it isn't. Why?
I made these two divs overlap. Only difference between them is the width (one is set to 50% the other to 100%) but changing the width doesn't change a thing when it comes to this problem. I made the text div 50% because I wanted the text to not come in contact with the plants on the image.
[The circled area of this image isn't supposed to be empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btxGW.png)

[It's even worse on small screens. The text here overlaps the footer (It shouldnt)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du1va.png)

```css
.intro-img-div{
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-content: center;
    margin:auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}
.menu-intro-img{

    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu-intro-text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 50%;

    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu-intro-h1{
    font-size: 3em;
}
.menu-intro-text p{
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<main>
      <h1 class="text-centered">Our Menu</h1>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="menu-intro">  

          <div class="intro-img-div">
              <img src="style/img/menuintroimg.jpeg" alt="Background image of our food" class="menu-intro-img">
          </div>

              <div class="menu-intro-text">
                  <h1 class="menu-intro-h1">A look at <span class="red-text">Jacque's</span>

                  </h1>
                  <p>Scroll down and see what we have to offer!</p>
              </div>


      </div>
    </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `.menu-intro-text` shouldn't have any surrounding whitespace, why does it have both a `margin` and a `padding`?

```
.menu-intro-text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 300px;

    vertical-align: middle;   /* <--- remove */

    margin-bottom: 30px;      /* <--- remove */ 
    margin: 20px;             /* <--- remove */
    padding: 20px;            /* <--- remove */
}
```

It seems to me that if you want two items to overlap, it makes no sense to give one of them a margin and a padding that the other does not have.

You should also remove `vertical-align: middle`, as this will inherently create whitespace at the top when there is space left over at the bottom.

> The text here overlaps the footer (It shouldnt)

Because of the extra margin, your image is taller than the 300px height you planned for, coming in at 340px total (300px + 20px top margin + 20px bottom margin), though you arguably don't see the bottom margin.

Furthermore, even in the 300px you have when you ignore the margins, there is a further "waste" of 40px (20px top, 20px bottom) due to the padding you set, though (again) you arguably don't see the bottom padding.

Comment: Not to mention that `margin-bottom` is useless as it is overwritten by `margin`. And there is a default browser margin on `h1` as well

Comment: @MaxiGui: Isn't that a specificity thing? Or is it purely the order of arranging `margin` and `margin-bottom`? I'm not sure, actually. I don't tend to mix them.

Comment: for margin-bottom it is because of how the person ordered it. but based on the fact that there is couple `h1` in code that is not recommanded. I guess he is a beginner

Comment: even when I remove margin and padding there's still some sort of space

Comment: @AnđeloMotika: It might be a lot quicker to just use the dev tools to figure out where the whitespace is coming from. If you don't know what the dev tools are, it is absolutely worth taking the time to learn about them. Google "[your browser] dev tools" to find out more.

Comment: You set `vertical-align: middle;` so it will be always space

Comment: @MaxiGui: Great catch! Added to the answer.